# wrangler dev seems to work, but wrangler publish doesn't work, gets error "Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0"

Tags: javascript, json, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I'm trying to make a serverless API using workers, and when I run "wrangler dev" in the command line, the local server is made and I am able to go to the page without error. A json object is shown on the page which is what I think I want since it is a "GET" request.

When I run "wrangler publish" and go to the published site, it says "Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0". I've looked at many links and I cannot find how to see what is wrong. In Cloudflare, the the logs show that the GET requests go through.

Does anyone know what I can do next to try and solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, there was an error when I inspect the page, and I used that in combination with console.logs and the cloudflare worker site to fix the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).